# Cloning tabs in Tab Control on button click in Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol

so I have a Homepage on one of the TabPages on winform TabControl. I have a button, that adds a new tab using this `Tabs.TabPages.Add("Homepage");`

But TabPages.Add() just adds a new blank page, how would i clone my HomePage on the new tab? For instance, if my homepage has a button "Click me", when i open a new tab, I want it to have the same button "Click me" linked to the same event "ClickMe_click". Like a Chrome Tab control. I couldn't find any event or method built in for TabControl on msdn, unless i missed it.

Any help or hint or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can't clone a tabpage so easily. Better: Create a UserControl, and add an instance to the page. To clone repeat.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "Create UserControl"? And also, none of overloads TabPages.Add() method takes Control as argument. I'm new to tabs so sorry if i'm asking stupid question.

Comment: Look into [UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813036/why-do-we-use-usercontrol/22813601#22813601)!  - You can add controls to it just as you would with a form or with a TabPage. Very useful if you want multiple copies of the same layout. (Note that no run-time date will be copied, of course) - No, it will be a two-step process: Add the NewPage and then a new instance of your UC: yourPage.Control.Add(new usercontro());

Comment: Yea I looked up UserControl. I'm surprised I never used it before. It might actually work. Thanks @TaW

Comment: @TaW having a UserControl did the trick for me. I created UserControl class, created new TabPage, used  Tabs.SelectTab(++TabCount) method to select the newly created page, followed by Tabs.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(new Homepage_userControl()); to add the usercontrol to the tab page.

Comment: Please post your suggestion as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't clone a tabpage so easily. One can [try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26315485/adding-a-twin-tabpage-to-tabcontrol-through-a-user-command/26315755?s=1|49.9518#26315755) but the recommended way is:

- Create a [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) and add all the controls you want on your page. Make it `Dock=Fill` and add any code that connects the controls. You can layout as freely as you would in a form or a tabpage..
- Whenever you want another page of this type, add a new tabpage and add an instance of the `UserControl` to its `Controls` collection.

Note: All controls on your `UserControl` by default are `private`. This is not really different from placing them on the tabpage directly. But now they are private members of the UC class, so your form and its code can't access them.

Looks like a problem when you're new to it. But if you look at it right, it is a good oportunity to create a leaner & cleaner interface.

- Solution 1: Change the control modifiers to `public` as needed
- Solution 2: Add properties to expose those data you really want to expose.

Also note: You can do all layout but can do so only in the UC designer. After adding to a form or tabpage there will be no embedded designer..