# Is there any way to use a form design in an other one with visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I'm new in C#, and I'm trying to use a design I made in a form and put it inside the other one. In Java this is possible with Scene builder. You just press include and choose your FXML file. Is there any way to do that in Visual Studio??

Comment: Are you using winforms? webforms? WPF? Xamarin? Something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7692113/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this.

The word is **User Control**. Drag and drop everything to your newly created `User Control` , then after you made it, you can choose it later from the **Tool box** in **Visual Studio**, and also can use Drag and drop your `User Control` like any other tool to existing forms.

Comment: For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50203323/cloning-tabs-in-tab-control-on-button-click-in-winforms/50204174#50204174)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for UserControl.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do that in Visual Studio??

Yes there is, you can use a `UserControl` if you are targeting `Winform`. Similar exists for WPF as well.